# How can i give text a rainbow color effect?

Tags: html, css, gradient, heading

[image: Example of text with a gradiant]

How could I replicate the above effect? So far I tried the following, but the text is just white:

```css
     h1 {
        background-image: var(--rainbow-gradient,#fff);
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -moz-background-clip: text;
        -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2rem #000);
        text-shadow: none!important;
    }
```

```html
    <H1>Hello world</H1>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stack Overflow is a question and answer site focused on programming questions. Do you have a programming question?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Webkit has some CSS to do things like this but its not necessarily supported by every browsers.  Have a look at `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` and `-webkit-background-clip: text;` combined with an elements background color/gradient.

Comment: h1 {
    background-image: var(--rainbow-gradient,#fff);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2rem #000);
    text-shadow: none!important;
}

Comment: Put your attempt in the question. Even better use the `<>` button to create a runnable snippet.

Comment: Replace `var(--rainbow-gradient,#fff);` with `linear-gradient(-90deg,#adfbda 0,#35c3ff 30%,#fda399 50%,#76d880 70%,#ebf38b 90%,#adfbda 100%);`. In future, include what you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working version:

```css
div {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red,yellow,green,blue);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 17vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Most browsers support it, but it *is* non-standard so don't rely on it for crucial things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one step ahead from the given solution, try this:

HTML :

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#ff7e5f,#feb47b,#ffed86,#9feb8f,#5fbfff,#9b8eff);
    background-size: 700% 700%;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    animation: grad 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes grad{
  0%{
    background-position:0% 50%}to{background-position:100% 50%
  }
}
```